I am trying created a multipart/mixed payload from json using dataweave but issue with boundry
I am trying to create below expected payload which is in multipart/mixed format  from i/p json to send it through Request component in anypoint.
I need to get rid of the boundary "--XX" per expected payload.
input: {
"salesOrderNumber": "129467145",
"items": [
{
"salesOrderItemNumber": "20",
"firstPlannedShipDate": "2024-05-27T00:00:00.000Z",
"firstPlannedDeliveryDate": "2024-06-25T00:00:00.000Z"
},
{
"salesOrderItemNumber": "40",
"firstPlannedShipDate": "2024-05-27T00:00:00.000Z",
"firstPlannedDeliveryDate": "2024-06-25T00:00:00.000Z"
}
]
}
Dataweave:
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::util::Coercions
output multipart/mixed boundary="batch"
var innerJsonPart ={
"ZZ1_FCDD_SDI": "\/Date(1719273600)\/",
"ZZ1_FCSD_SDI": "\/Date(1716768000)\/"
}
 
---
parts:payload.items map(item, index)->(
  {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_mychangeset" ++ (index+1)  ,
    },
      content: {
          parts: {part0:
  {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/http",
      "Content-Transfer-Encoding": "binary"
    },
    content: write( { parts: [
                    {                           
                        content: "PATCH A_SalesOrderItem(SalesOrder='0" ++ (payload.salesOrderNumber) ++"',SalesOrderItem='" ++ (item.salesOrderItemNumber) ++"') HTTP/1.1"
                    },
                    {                            headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json"
                        },
                        content: innerJsonPart
                    }
    ]    
    }, "multipart/mixed",{boundary:
"XX"}),         
          },   
          }}})

output:
 --batch    
    Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_mychangeset1
    
    --changeset_mychangeset1
    Content-Type: application/http
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
    
    PATCH A_SalesOrderItem(SalesOrder='0129467145',SalesOrderItem='20') HTTP/1.1
    Content-Type: application/json
    
    {
    "ZZ1_FCDD_SDI" : "\/Date(1719273600)\/",
    "ZZ1_FCSD_SDI" : "\/Date(1716768000)\/"
     }
    --changeset_mychangeset1--
    --batch
    
    Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_mychangeset2
    
    --changeset_mychangeset2
    Content-Type: application/http
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
    
    PATCH A_SalesOrderItem(SalesOrder='0129467145',SalesOrderItem='40') HTTP/1.1
    Content-Type: application/json
    
    {
    "ZZ1_FCDD_SDI" : "\/Date(1719273600)\/",
    "ZZ1_FCSD_SDI" : "\/Date(1716768000)\/"
     }
    --changeset_mychangeset2--    
    --batch--


What do you mean that you need to remove the boundary? What is your expected output?

Your script doesn't work because payload1 is not defined. Please edit the example to fix it.

I don't think multipart without a boundary would be a valid request. unless it only has single part. boundary are used to separate different part in multipart payloads

I'm not sure DataWeave supports directly this kind of transformation which seems to be the OData batch request format. I found a solution which is a bit of a hack by concatenating the strings of each part instead of trying to force DataWeave multipart support for it.
Script:
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::util::Coercions
var innerPayloadPart = {
  ZZ1_FCDD_SDI: "/Date(1719273600)/",
  ZZ1_FCSD_SDI: "/Date(1716768000)/"
}
output multipart/mixed  boundary="batch"
---

  parts: payload.items map (item, index) -> ({
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_mychangeset" ++ (index + 1)
    },
    content: {
      parts: {
        part0: {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/http",
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding": "binary"
          },
          content:  "PATCH A_SalesOrderItem(SalesOrder='0 $(payload.salesOrderNumber)',SalesOrderItem='$(item.salesOrderItemNumber)') HTTP/1.1\n" 
                ++ "Content-Type: application/json\n\n"
                ++ write(innerPayloadPart, "application/json")
        }
      }
    }
  })

Output:
--batch
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_mychangeset1

--changeset_mychangeset1
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

PATCH A_SalesOrderItem(SalesOrder='0 129467145',SalesOrderItem='20') HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "ZZ1_FCDD_SDI": "/Date(1719273600)/",
  "ZZ1_FCSD_SDI": "/Date(1716768000)/"
}
--changeset_mychangeset1--

--batch
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_mychangeset2

--changeset_mychangeset2
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

PATCH A_SalesOrderItem(SalesOrder='0 129467145',SalesOrderItem='40') HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "ZZ1_FCDD_SDI": "/Date(1719273600)/",
  "ZZ1_FCSD_SDI": "/Date(1716768000)/"
}
--changeset_mychangeset2--

--batch--

I removed the extra backslashes that didn't seem to be converted to JSON.
